# javascript image.width gives 0 only when served but works proper locally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image

I was rendering an image in React by setting image width using js and was setting to img style

```
let img = new Image();
img.src = "image_url";
let i_width = (img.width * 2.54) / 30;

 <img src="image_url" style={{width:${i_width}mm}}
```

which works fine locally, but when served the value of img.width remains 0 for all images. this issue was not there before and I have not changed it lately, but all of a sudden, it's not working.

also tried img.naturalWidth both works fine locally but not when served.

Answer (score 0):

Images are asynchronously loaded over the network. You can't get its dimension immediately. You'd need to subscribe to `load` event to get correct width.

```js
let img = new Image();
img.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLMUr.jpg?s=256&g=1";
console.log('sync', img.width);

img.addEventListener('load', () => {
  console.log('onload', img.width)
})
```

Comment: yes you are right did the same it works.